# Databricks error while importing a notebook: The bucket name parameter must be specified when requesting a bucket's location

Tags: amazon-s3, bucket, databricks, was

I trying to learn spark on databricks.
I set up a databricks account. 
when I try to import a notebook from url I get a message:

Import failed with error: Failed to import https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/6244269837918943/3546103630347710/4066658260255490/latest.html: The bucket name parameter must be specified when requesting a bucket's location

The url works fine. I don't know how to approach this problem. AWS storage set up was done according to databricks instruction and it passed all the tests.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the naming of the bucket - there should be no dots '.' in the name. Now the bucket has name without dots and import  works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It is not a problem with importing notebooks via URL.

This is a problem with importing notebooks via URL. Can you instead download the page using your web browser, download "Just the HTML" and then you'll be able to import it using file-based notebook import.

Comment: I get similar type of error:
Error uploading file: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /upload/import-files. Reason:
<pre>    The bucket name parameter must be specified when requesting a bucket&apos;s location</pre></p>
<hr />
</body>
</html>

Comment: @Meehow actually it sounds like there really is a problem with the AWS storage setup in your account, I'm able to import the notebook via URL now.